# Droid - what won't function properly on device if I disable background data usage for google play store?

Tags: google-play-store, motorola-droid-razr

I just upgraded to a new droid razor maxx from an older version.  With the older version I never went over my 150 mb of data.  Since I received the new phone Google Play Store is eating up my data and I went over my limit within 3 days.

Why does google play eat up all my data using mostly "background" usage, when I am not even accessing it?

What won't function properly on device if I disable background data usage for google play store?

Answer (score 3):

I have done that months ago for the very same reason, so I can tell from my own experience:

- you will no longer receive update notifications while on mobile data (naturally)
- no apps will auto-update while on mobile data (again, naturally)

Both is what you want. I encountered no more restrictions. Update notifications coming in as soon as the device is connected to any WiFi, updates I either do on WiFi only.

What I didn't try is to force an update/install while on mobile data. In theory, this should work *as long as you keep the app in foreground* – but the installation will stall as soon as you switch to another app (as then Google Play no longer is the "foreground app"). But that's the *theory* only, as I've never tested it.

Comment: Anytime, Tara! If an answer solved your issue, please consider "accepting" it (by clicking the checkmark next to it), so other users can identify solutions. Of course you might want to verify it first :)