# Will it be a good idea to block Google play store to save my data?

Tags: applications, google-play-store

I am new to android phones (using one for the first time since last two days). I have a limited data plan, so I want to save as much data as I can. But when I was monitoring my data usage, I observed that certain system apps, in particular **Google services framework** and **Google play store** are eating way to much data even when I am not using them at all. So I have installed **Opera Max**, where I can block apps. Now I have two questions-

1. What is Google services frameworks?
2. If I block these two apps, is there going to be a problem?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: For *Google Play Store,* see [my answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/58627/16575). Also follow up its links, e.g. to [What won't function properly on device if I disable background data usage for google play store?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/55562/16575)

Answer (score 0):

Your phone would be a paper weight. Most of those app blockers are garbage. They eat up resources and battery life.

Most google apps require a network connect to work.

Best bet simply set your phone to wifi only when you can. Turn on wifi only updates. Something like Tasker can help if you can get past the learning curve.